# Aligning columns in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

If i use this layout, everything is ok

See this Image:

[image]

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#000000" android:layout_margin="10dip" android:padding="10dip" >

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <TextView android:id="@+id/n1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"  android:text="aaaaa a aaaaaaaaa:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/c1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"  android:layout_column="3"  android:text="15"></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/n2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"  android:text="aaaaaaa aaaaa:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/c2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_column="3" android:text="12"></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/n3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="aaa:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/c3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"  android:layout_column="3"  android:text="14"></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/n4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="aaa:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/c4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"  android:layout_column="3"  android:text="18"></TextView>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/n5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:text="aaaaaa aaaaaaaa:"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/c5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#ffffff"  android:layout_column="2"  android:text="70"></TextView>

    </TableRow> 
</TableLayout>
```

But if i set android:layout_column="3"  for the second textview in the last row, this shows http://www.lukafinzgar.com/nekul.png .

How should i set the attributes to get all the numbers in the third column?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "android:layout_width" and "android:layout_height" in TableLayout tag only. not anywhere else. And use "android:layout_weight" in each element of TableRow tag to adjust the columns horizontally.Try the below coding.

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/cpotl1textview1"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Total Outstanding" />
                <EditText android:id="@+id/cpotl1edittext1"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/cpotl1textview2"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Claim Amount" />
                <EditText android:id="@+id/cpotl1edittext2"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/cpotl1textview3"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="Select Message" />
                <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/cpotl1autocompletetextview"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                     android:hint="Templates" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

Thanks for opportunity.

Comment: My app crashes when I remove `layout_with` and `layout_height`. Error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaa a aaaaaaaaa:"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/c1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:text="15"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaaa aaaaa:"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/c2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaa:"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/c3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:text="14"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaa:"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/c4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:text="18"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/n5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaa aaarrrrrrraaaaa:"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/c5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:text="70"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think having `layout_width` more than once in each element would enforce it!